# Jquery hover fires both handlers when moving mouse qucikly

Tags: jquery, hover, performance

On fast movement of the Mouse (As always, only in IE) both hover handlers are triggered, so nothing appears. 
I tried using hoverIntend, but that plugin messes with e.pageX/Y
Any ideas how to fix that, i have not succeeded after 5 hours.

```
yOffset = 10;
xOffset = 30;      

$("img.hover-preview").hover(function(e){
//alert('hover');

this.t = this.title;
this.title = "";  
var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";

preview_link = $('#' + this.id + '-url').attr('src'); //Get the src of the bigger preview image   
zoom_link = $('#' + this.id + '-url-zoom').attr('src'); //Get the src of the ZOOM image   

//Output of the preview element
$("body").append("<div id='hover-preview-active'><img src='"+ preview_link +"' alt='Loading Image Preview' /><span>"
                 + Drupal.t("Press and hold Z key to zoom") + "</span></div>");    

$("#hover-preview-active")
  .css("top", (e.pageY - yOffset) + "px")
  .css("left",(e.pageX + xOffset) + "px")
  .fadeIn("fast");
},

function(){
  this.title = this.t;  
  $("#hover-preview-active").remove();
});
```

Comment: it is working with the solution from aditya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your hover out function:

```
function(){
  if($("#hover-preview-active").is(":animated"))
      return;

  this.title = this.t;  
  $("#hover-preview-active").remove();
});
```

That will stop the function from executing if your `#hover-preview-active` is animating when it is called.